# AEM Run modes – which OSGI config gets picked-up?

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have an osgi config which exist both in config.author and config.dev. And here is the run mode of my AEM server Run Modes = [dev-est, dev, crx3, author]. I am noticing that config.author OSGI is getting picked up before config.dev. I thought config.dev should take precedence over config.author but that’s not the case. When I delete config.author config, then only config.dev gets picked up. Can somebody explain this please?

Run Modes = [dev-est, dev, crx3, author].

1. config.author
2. config.dev

Comment: Check this may help you!  http://www.sgaemsolutions.com/2017/03/run-modes-with-use-cases-in-aem-62-part1.html

Comment: Look at the answer for the explanation. Use config.author.dev to add more weight to your dev config if want that to be picked up. Think of config.author for the most common values you want to reuse or the default value in case no other run mode (dev, qa, prod) was specified.